# Java reduce a collection of string to a map of occurence

Tags: java, mapreduce, java-stream

Consider the a list as `id1_f, id2_d, id3_f, id1_g`, how can I use stream to get a reduced map in format of `<String, Integer>`of statistics like:

```
id1 2
id2 1
id3 1
```

Note: the key is part before `_`. Is `reduce` function can help here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will get the job done:

```
Map<String, Long> map = Stream.of("id1_f", "id2_d", "id3_f", "id1_g")
  .collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(v -> v.split("_")[0],
    Collectors.counting())
  );
```

Comment: I would use `v -> v.split("_")[0]` to account for the possibility that there might not be a `_` in a string.

Comment: @rgettman it’s debatable which is the better way to handle absence of `'_'` here. If it should be present, an exception is much better than silently using the entire string. Besides that, `substring` is more efficient than splitting into an array of strings we’re not interested in, as we only care for the first one. The minimum, a developer should do here, is to use `v.split("_", 2)` to avoid searching for more occurrences of `"_"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `toMap` collector:

```
myList.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap((String s) -> s.split("_")[0], 
                   (String s) -> 1, Math::addExact);
```

if you care about the order of the elements then dump the result into a `LinkedHashMap`.

```
myList.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap((String s) -> s.split("_")[0], 
                   (String s) -> 1, Math::addExact, 
                     LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-stream approach using [Map::merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
Map<String, Integer> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
myList.forEach(s -> result.merge(s.split("_")[0], 1, Math::addExact));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to *count* the elements, I'd suggest using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [`Multiset`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html) interface, which is dedicated to such purpose.

The definition of `Multiset` from its JavaDoc:

> A collection that supports order-independent equality, like `Set`, but may have duplicate elements. A multiset is also sometimes called a *bag*.
>
> Elements of a multiset that are equal to one another are referred to as *occurrences* of the same single element. The total number of occurrences of an element in a multiset is called the *count* of that element.

Here are two ways to use it:

1) Without the Stream API:

```
ImmutableMultiset<String> multiset2 = ImmutableMultiset.copyOf(Lists.transform(
        list, str -> StringUtils.substringBefore(str, "_")
));
```

2) Using the Stream API:

```
ImmutableMultiset<String> multiset = list.stream()
        .map(str -> StringUtils.substringBefore(str, "_"))
        .collect(ImmutableMultiset.toImmutableMultiset());
```

Note that instead of using something like `s.split("_")[0]`, I used [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)'s [`StringUtils.substringBefore`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBefore-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), which I find much more readable.

You retrieve the counts of the elements using [`Multiset.count()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html#count-java.lang.Object-) method.